# my Peace Lily is getting droopy but I’m not sure why

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, peace-lily

i got this peace lily on May 17th from a garden centre (in england) i’ve inserted a pic from the day i got it, nice and perky and upright. i’ve been watering as instructed when the soil begins to dry out, giving it a good amount and making sure to check the pot for standing water. i have used bottled mineral water rather than tap water as i was told tap water can be bad for them. i also mist it every day or so with a fine mister. it stays indoors on my desk 3 to 4 feet away from an East facing window. i try to open the blind early so it gets a bit of morning sun but that is not every day because of British weather. so mostly it says in relatively low light. the temp in my room is ~18c

over the last few days however, it’s getting droopy and not lifting up much. i watered it a few days ago when i noticed it looking thirsty and although it lifted a little it still looked thirsty so i gave more which perked it up a bit, but it’s now drooping again already. i am not sure what chemicals they used at the garden centre but there are currently 9 spathes which i’m assuming are because of fertilisers, does it need more water whilst flowering? it has good leaf colour and shine, the leaves are bouncy and stems seem to have good integrity. i have included another pic of the drooping, and i also took it outside to have a look at the root system after watering to see if it looked overly pot bound. i know this isn’t the usual ‘dramatic’ wilting, but i’m a new plant mum and really want to take good care. drooping again within 2 days of watering i figured i might be going wrong somewhere.

[image: peace lily may 17]

[image: peace lily june 8]

[image: peace lily root system]

Answer (score 1):

You could try giving it a little extra help with some structural support. They make plant props which you could push into the soil. Then you would simply tie the main shoots up to the prop. If you do decide to go this route you might think about getting it a larger pot and reporting/adding prop at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The roots are firm and white indicating everything is fine there.  It is more likely that the plant is spreading out in response to lower light levels.

There is enough soil showing in the root ball that it does not need re potting soon. If you  move it to a higher light position you will have to take care not to let it dry out as this plant collapses if too dry.  Consider inserting a cotton or plastic wick into the pot and adding a water reservoir underneath.  I have also let the bottom of the pot sit in water when the plants are in high light but that is a little tricky to manage.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i really wasn’t sure. it didn’t look to me like it needed repotting either but the quick drooping made me wonder. the water also seemed to run through quite quickly so i was trying to take it steady to give it chance to soak up. i really don’t know what to do about the light because i want to keep it in my room...do peace lillies get on well with grow lights or anything like that, or no?

Comment: @elavarion any kind of light will do. Even direct sun is fine if the plant has access to water....